# Running multiple PHP scripts at once from command line initiated by cron jobs

Tags: php, linux, multithreading, cron

I have a question concerning cron jobs.

Here is a brief look at the situation:

1. I call a php script every minute (*****) (PHP CLI).
2. The PHP script makes a database request to check if there are any emails to send for that specific minute and sends them accordingly.
3. The PHP script needs more than 1 minute for execution (huge database -> lots of emails to send -> takes time even though using multiple threads)
4. The same PHP script gets called the next minute (*****), while its first execution hasn't finished its execution yet.

Will the first execution interrupt, when the script is called again (every minute it is called), even though the first execution hasn't finished yet?

I hope the situation is clear for you.

Operating System: obviously Linux ...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the first execution interrupt, when the script is called again
>   (every minute it is called), even though the first execution hasn't
>   finished yet?

No, it will not interrupt unless you handle this case in the script being called. A common way to solve the problem is using *locks*, or implementing the [*mutual exclusion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion).

There are numerous ways to implement locking in PHP, and there is no "best" way. You can whether pick one that suits best for the back ends available on your platform, or implement multiple lockers for different platforms and maybe even different use cases. Beware, you should make sure that you are always using the same locker for specific jobs on the same host!

Some of the popular tools that can be used as back ends for locking:

- [flock](http://php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.flock.php)
- [Redis](https://redis.io/)
- [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/) (`GET_LOCK`, `IS_USED_LOCK`, `RELEASE_LOCK`)

## Example

The following code implements an abstract locker class and a sample implementation based on [phpredis](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis) extension.

```
namespace Acme;

class Factory {
  /// @var \Redis
  private static $redis;

  public static function redis() {
    if (!static::$redis) {
      try {
        static::$redis = new \Redis();
        // In practice you should fetch the host from a configuration object.
        static::$redis->pconnect('/tmp/redis.sock');
      } catch (\Exception $e) {
        trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
      }
    }
    return static::$redis;
  }

  /**
   * @param mixed $id ID of a job or group of jobs
   * @return AbstractLocker
   */
  public static function locker($id) {
    return new RedisLocker($id);
  }
}


abstract class AbstractLocker {
  abstract public function __construct($id);
  abstract public function lock();
  abstract public function unlock();
  abstract public function isLocked();
}


class RedisLocker extends AbstractLocker {
  /// Key prefix
  const PREFIX = 'lock/';

  /// @var \Redis
  private static $redis;
  /// @var string DB item key
  private $key;
  /// @var int Expiration time in seconds
  private $expire = 86400;

  /**
   * @param mixed $id ID of a job or group of jobs
   */
  public function __construct($id) {
    if (!static::$redis) {
      static::$redis = Factory::redis();
    }
    $this->key = static::PREFIX . '/' . $id;
  }

  public function lock() {
    $this->_fixDeadlocks();
    $r = static::$redis;

    // Set the key to the current process ID
    // within a transaction (see http://redis.io/topics/transactions).
    $r->multi();
    $result = $r->setnx($this->key, getmypid());
    $r->setTimeout($this->key, $this->expire);
    $r->exec();

    return (bool) $result;
  }

  public function unlock() {
    $r = static::$redis;

    // Delete the key from DB within a transaction.
    $r->multi();
    $result = $r->delete($this->key);
    $r->exec();

    return (bool) $result;
  }

  public function isLocked() {
    $this->_fixDeadlocks();
    return (bool) static::$redis->exists($this->key);
  }

  private function _fixDeadlocks() {
    $r = static::$redis;

    if (!$r->exists($this->key) || (!$pid = $r->get($this->key))) {
      return;
    }

    $running = (bool) posix_kill($pid, 0);
    if ($pid && $running) {
      // Another process is running normally
      return;
    }

    if (!$running) {
      // Process is not running, so the keys must not exist
      if ($r->exists($this->key) && $pid == $r->get($this->key)) {
        // Deadlock found
        $this->unlock();
      }
    }
  }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Usage

$id = 'Bubbles';
$locker = Factory::locker($id);
if ($locker->isLocked()) {
  trigger_error("$id job is locked");
  exit(1);
}
$locker->lock();
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) { echo '. o O '; usleep(1e6); }
echo PHP_EOL;
$locker->unlock();
```

### Testing

**Terminal A**

```
$ php script.php
. o O . o O . o O . o O . o O . o
```

**Terminal B**

```
$ php script.php
Notice: Bubbles job is locked in /home/ruslan/tmp/script.php on line 121
```

Answer (score 0):

No, a new process will be spawned. A quick test shows this:

```
shell> cat /root/run_sleep.sh 
#!/bin/bash

sleep 10000

shell> crontab -l
* * * * * sh /root/run_sleep.sh
```

You can check with `ps` that different processes are created each minute:

```
shell> ps aux | grep run[_]
root      2316  0.0  0.0 113120  1192 ?        Ss   22:46   0:00 sh /root/run_sleep.sh
root      2339  0.0  0.0 113120  1188 ?        Ss   22:47   0:00 sh /root/run_sleep.sh
root      2363  0.0  0.0 113120  1192 ?        Ss   22:48   0:00 sh /root/run_sleep.sh
root      2388  0.0  0.0 113120  1192 ?        Ss   22:49   0:00 sh /root/run_sleep.sh
root      2410  0.0  0.0 113120  1196 ?        Ss   22:50   0:00 sh /root/run_sleep.sh
root      2434  0.0  0.0 113120  1196 ?        Ss   22:51   0:00 sh /root/run_sleep.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

No, each call to the script is independent of the others, however you should consider that while the scripts run at the same time each time the database will be overloaded ... it would be advisable to run the script every two minutes at least (*/2)

Answer (score 0):

its like Pepo talked. This open a new process. Some situations its can be a problem. To solve this you can use the JobQueue, like in Laravel. Or you can create a better task list to cronjob of your aplication process, similar to jobqueue, some like a table or file with list to process actions/functions and a status to item pending/processing/finished.
With this problem to multiple process, remeber to check you data before process.